# What does a key sequence beginning with A- mean in emacs?

Tags: coffeescript, xemacs

I'm playing with [coffee-mode](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode) for editing coffee-script, but I'm a total emacs newb.

In coffee-mode there are key bindings like "A-r" for compiling a buffer and "A-M-r" (I assume the "M" is meta) to open a coffeescript repl. However I can't find which key "A" refers to (it's really hard to google for A-).

Comment: Maybe it's assumed you have a PC-compatible keyboard and A means 'Alt'. Compare with http://wttools.sourceforge.net/emacs-stuff/emacs-keybindings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. "A-r" apparently is the command key and r on a mac!

Comment: so... what is it on a non-mac?

Comment: No, window key is super (denoted by s)

Comment: A- is the same as alt +.  On some systems it's different from meta.  In X the windows keys can be set to meta with "setxkbmap -option altwin:meta_win" and then the alt keys will be A- in emacs.